# Print all items in Recyclerview to pdf file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have been stuck on this for over 2 weeks. I tried everything and search everywhere but nothing worked.

I have an android app with sqlite database.
I made a recyclerview with a custom adapter because every item in the recyclerview consists of 80 Textviews.
I want to print every row of the recyclerview in a seperate page but in the same document. when I try to print the rows of recyclerview, I get only the visible rows on the screen which is the first and the second row only while my recyclerview consists of at least 10 to 20 rows. I'm using the latest version of android studio and Kotlin.
here is what I have so far

this is my custom Adapter

```
class BianProductsAdapter(mCtx: Context,val bianproducts: ArrayList<LV_BProducts>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BianProductsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
val mCtx = mCtx

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val lbpid = itemView.bianproductid
    val lbpproductname = itemView.bianproductname
    val lbpproductunit = itemView.bianproductunit
    val lbpproductquantity = itemView.bianproductquantity
    val lbpproductoriginalprice = itemView.bianproductoriginalprice
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BianProductsAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v : View= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.lo_b_products,parent,false)
    return BianProductsAdapter.ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BianProductsAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val df = DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00")
    val bianproduct : LV_BProducts = bianproducts[position]
    holder.lbpid.text = bianproduct.lvbp_id.toString()
    holder.lbpproductname.text = bianproduct.lvbp_product_name.toString()
    holder.lbpproductunit.text = bianproduct.lvbp_unit.toString()
    holder.lbpproductquantity.text = bianproduct.lvbp_quantity.toString()
    holder.lbpproductoriginalprice.text = "$"+ df.format(bianproduct.lvbp_original_price.toFloat())
       }

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return bianproducts.size
}
```

}

and this is Activity.kt`

```
class BProductsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
inner class MyPrintDocumentAdapter(private var context: Context)
    : PrintDocumentAdapter() {
    private var pageHeight: Int = 0
    private var pageWidth: Int = 0
    private var myPdfDocument: PdfDocument? = null

    private fun drawPage(
            page: PdfDocument.Page,
            pagenumber: Int
    ) {
        var pagenum = pagenumber
        val canvas = page.canvas
        pagenum++ 
        val titleBaseLine = 72
        val leftMargin = 54
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = Color.BLACK
        val pageInfo = page.info
    }

    private fun pageInRange(pageRanges: Array<PageRange>, page: Int): Boolean {
        for (i in pageRanges.indices) {
            if (page >= pageRanges[i].start && page <= pageRanges[i].end)
                return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onLayout(
            oldAttributes: PrintAttributes?,
            newAttributes: PrintAttributes?,
            cancellationSignal: android.os.CancellationSignal?,
            callback: LayoutResultCallback?,
            extras: Bundle?
    ) {
        myPdfDocument = newAttributes?.let { PrintedPdfDocument(context, it) }

        val height = newAttributes?.mediaSize?.heightMils
        val width = newAttributes?.mediaSize?.heightMils

        height?.let {
            pageHeight = it / 1000 * 72
        }

        width?.let {
            pageWidth = it / 1000 * 72
        }

        if (cancellationSignal != null) {
            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled) {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onLayoutCancelled()
                }
                return
            }
        }

        if (totalpages > 0) {
            val builder =
                    PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("print_output.pdf").setContentType(
                            PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT
                    )
                            .setPageCount(totalpages)

            val info = builder.build()
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true)
            }
        } else {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count is zero.")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onWrite(
            pages: Array<out PageRange>?,
            destination: ParcelFileDescriptor?,
            cancellationSignal: android.os.CancellationSignal?,
            callback: WriteResultCallback?
    ) {
        for (i in 0 until totalpages) {

            if (pageInRange(pages as Array<PageRange>, i)) {
                val newPage = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(
                        pageWidth,
                        pageHeight, i
                ).create()

               if (cancellationSignal != null) {
                    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled) {
                        if (callback != null) {
                            callback.onWriteCancelled()
                        }
                        myPdfDocument?.close()
                        myPdfDocument = null
                        return
                    }
                }

                val page = myPdfDocument?.startPage(newPage)
                val content: View = mybprv.get(i) //mybprv is the ID of my recyclerview
                val measureWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        page!!.canvas.width,
                        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
                )
                val measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        page.canvas.height,
                        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
                )

                content.measure(measureWidth, measuredHeight)
                content.layout(0, 0, page.canvas.width, page.canvas.height)
                if (page != null) {
                    content.draw(page.canvas)
                }

                myPdfDocument?.finishPage(page)
              }
        }

        try {
            if (destination != null) {
                myPdfDocument?.writeTo(
                        FileOutputStream(
                                destination.fileDescriptor
                        )
                )
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString())
            }
            return
        } finally {
            myPdfDocument?.close()
            myPdfDocument = null
        }

        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onWriteFinished(pages)
        }
    }
}

fun printDocument(view: View) {
    val printManager = this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager

    val jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document"

    printManager.print(jobName, MyPrintDocumentAdapter(this), null)
}


companion object{
    lateinit var bpdbHandler: DBHandler
    private var totalpages =0
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b_products)
    bpdbHandler = DBHandler(this,null,null,1)
    populateList()

}


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.addbianproduct,menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    if (item.itemId==R.id.bainproductpage){
        printDocument(mybprv) // mybprv is the id of my recyclerview
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}



override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
   populateList()
}



private fun populateList() {
    val productslist : ArrayList<LV_BProducts>? = intent.getStringExtra("bid")?.let { bpdbHandler.getBianProducts(this, it) }
    val adapter = productslist?.let { BianProductsAdapter(this, it) }
    val rv : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mybprv)
    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
    rv.adapter = adapter
    rv.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
    if (productslist != null) {
        totalpages = productslist.size
    }
}
```

}

I get the exact records I want from the query and I can show all these records data in the recyclerview. My only problem is printing the recyclerview.
the number of pages printed = the number of rows returned by my query = the number of rows in my recyclerview
However, only visible rows which are row 1 and 2 get printed and the remaining pages are either a repetation of row 2 or empty

All your help is highly appreciated.
P.S: I know my code looks messy because it is a mix of two weeks searching and applying solutions from multiple sources until I got stuck where I am now.

Comment: A `RecyclerView` is designed for showing on a screen, where users can scroll. It is not designed for rendering a PDF. I suspect that you will have better luck using a real PDF generation API, such as iText, particularly for something as long as this.

Comment: I tried also with listview instead of recyclerview but no luck.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to show all rows to user and also be able to print them?

Comment: "I tried also with listview instead of recyclerview but no luck" -- that also is designed for scrolling. "Do you have any suggestion how to show all rows to user and also be able to print them?" -- I suggested using a real PDF generation API. If you do not want to do that, use a single `ConstraintLayout` (or whatever) that represents your "row". For each piece of data, populate that `ConstraintLayout` and render that row to the PDF. Do that in a loop, taking into account wherever you feel that you want a page break.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try and see how things will go. Again, Thank you sir for your help :)